# Is there a way to (simulate) speed up the time (so that 1 sec passes like 1 min) x60?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am creating a time based (time tracking) app using Laravel Carbon. I want to test the app by speeding up the time by x60. I am looking for something like a fast forward time testing environment. I want that seconds pass like minutes and minutes like hours. Is there a way to do this in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Carbonite: https://github.com/kylekatarnls/carbonite

```
Carbonite::speed(60);
```

As recommended in the official Carbon doc:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-testing

Comment: This is a rare situation but that package is great for the situation. I tested it, it is working great. I definitely will use it in the runtime situations.

Comment: As a side question @KyleK any idea how something like that (time accelerating) could be performed for crontabs and platform as well?

Comment: You should only test what is the responsibility of you app/library. You can rely on crontab, it's well tested, just replace crontab trigger by the direct run of the scripts.